# Why is a commit diverging when the PR is rebased on github?

Tags: git, github, npm, tags, commit

I have a really simple git situation, but for some reason I get the following problem. Let's assume the following starting point:

```
                H
master (1) - - (2)
```

I have my master branch, which I want to tag and push to github. I branch off master to `rel-0.0.x`, change the versions on `npm`'s `package.json`, commit, and tag.

```
master (1) - - (2)
rel-0.0.x        \ - - (3)
                        H & v0.0.x
```

In github, once the PR is reviewed, it's getting rebased and merged (with no other changes in master, so my assumption is that rebase shouldn't change the commit's parent). Why do I end up having this new commit (which is of course not tagged any more)? I can see in github, that the commit hash merged is different than the one I pushed. Should I merge instead of rebase? I do like a linear history, especially when it makes sense...

```
master (1) - - (2) - - (3') <-- this is fetched from github
rel-0.0.x        \ - - (3)
                        v0.0.x
```

I'd normally tag directly on github, but I want to use `npm`'s `version` tool, which bumps the version, commits, and tags automatically.

Comment: Why is the PR being rebased? That’s the cause of the 3’ being created.

Comment: Are you sure there are no extra commit(s) between `2` and `3'`?

Comment: With all due respect, why are people up-voting a question that could be answered with the first result from a google search?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger maybe I used the wrong search terms, because my mind was stuck on that tag getting diverged, but not the branch itself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation at https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-merges/

> The rebase and merge behavior on GitHub deviates slightly from git rebase. Rebase and merge on GitHub will always update the committer information and create new commit SHAs, whereas git rebase outside of GitHub does not change the committer information when the rebase happens on top of an ancestor commit. For more information about git rebase, see the "Git rebase" chapter from the Pro Git book.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find any information about *why* they chose to deviate from git. Is there any information about that decision?

Comment: @Jurrian - Nothing I'm aware of.